# REGEX to match domain in email addresses

Tags: regex, subdomain, email-validation

I'm currently using this *very relaxed* REGEX to validate email addresses:

```
(/(.+)@(.+)\.(.+){2,}/.test(emailAddress)
```

1. I believe that it only allows *min1_allowsDots@min1_allowsDots.min2* - is this correct?
2. How should I modify it to match only a particular domain - *anything@* ***onlythisdomain.com***?

TIA!

iSofia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(.+)@onlythisdomain\.(.+){2,}
```

This should do it.If `.com` is also fixed use

```
(.+)@onlythisdomain\.com
```

Comment: Thank you, vks. Appreciate your quick and concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

This simple RegEx basically says:

At least one character, then an "@", then literally "gmail.com".

If you change the domain to something else, it will  not match.

```js
var email = 'Godisgood@gmail.com';

var re = /.+\@gmail\.com/;

alert(email.match(re));
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. Almost impossible to effectively validate email addresses nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?
(company_domain1|company_domain2)\.ca$/g
```

It is a regex where you can validate the email including a specific domain such as
`jhosh@doctorgroup.ca` or `jhosh@doctors.ca` and it will match only if the email is ending with `@doctorgroup.ca` or `@doctors.ca`.

Comment: or ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+(@domain1.ca|@domain2.com)$